# Grade sync failed when starting new project in android studio 2.2.3. How to solve this issue?

Tags: android, android-studio

> Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process.
>                       This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>                       For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>                       Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>                       Please read the following process output to find out more:
>                       -----------------------
>                       Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: Post your gradle.properties file if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Try.

- Delete .gradle folder from c:\users\username.gradle
- File > Settings> On Settings dialog> select Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects) from left and set VM Options to -Xmx512m (i.e. write -Xmx512m under VM Options:) and
- press OK.

Close all applications running on your android studio and clear memory space and try again

Comment: I get this error after doing what you suggested.                          Error:The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
Java home is different.
Expecting: 'D:\android\jre' but was: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111'.
Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.